# ASP.NET MVC3 MEFContrib.Mvc3 Global Action Filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I am using the MEFContrib.MVC3 for DI into my MVC3 application.  This is working well injecting into my controllers.

I now need to create a custom global action filter that would also use DI.  I am able to successfully inject into my custom FilterProvider but not sure how to inject into the action filter itself.

**Filter Provider**

```
[Export(typeof(IFilterProvider))]
public class MefFilterAttributeProvider
    : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    [Import]
    IAccountService _AccountService;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MefFilterAttributeProvider(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        //MefContrib.Mvc3 successfully detects and injects
        this._AccountService = accountService;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();
        filters.AddRange(base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor));
        filters.AddRange(((IFilterProvider)GlobalFilters.Filters).GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor));

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            //Custom filter is detected in the list of filters
            //Do I need to add something here to pass the injection to the custom filter??
            yield return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Filter**

```
public class ClinicalFrameworkSessionSate : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    IAccountService accountService;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            //Session has timed out
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSites"] == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserDepts"] == null)
            {
                //Recreate the session
                User usr = this.accountService.GetUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserSites"] = usr.Sites.ToList();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserDepts"] = usr.Departments.ToList();
            }
        } 


    }

}
```

I have seen examples of how to inject using Ninject, AutoFac etc. but cannot seem to find example of using MefContrib and MefContrib.Mvc3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.